# mysql plus one a column

Tags: php, mysql

i use my own mvc framework.

and post action is :

```
function post($pid = 0 , $title = '')
{

    $pid = $this->input->clean($pid);

    $stm =$this->Post->query("UPDATE posts SET `show_count`=show_count+1 WHERE id = $pid"); 
    $stm->execute();
    $row = $this->Post->find()->where(array('id'=>$pid))->fetchOne();
    $this->layout->set('comments' ,  $this->comments($pid));
    $this->layout->set('row' , $row);
    $this->side();
    $this->layout->view('post'); 
    echo $this->layout->render($row['title']);
}
```

i want to when a record fetch from database plus one show_count column .

i use this query :

```
UPDATE posts SET show_count = show_count + 1 WHERE id = $pid
```

this right in localhost but in my shared host when run query instead of one pluses ,2 plus show_count column.

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: This should work correctly. You're certain it is adding two, and something else isn't going on, such as the query being executed twice?

Comment: Please post the PHP code you use to execute this statement.

Comment: i think query just one time execute.

Comment: Post the code that calls this function, as well as any rewrite rules your application uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working in your localhost but not your internet host.  The host is probably doing something behind the scenes that makes it not work.  Also, since you don't have access to all the configuration stuff on the host server, you probably won't be able to just fix it.

Simplest fix is to do it in the software layer (assuming $pid is unique).

First get the show_count.

Then:

```
$oldShowCount = the current show_count
$newShowCount = $oldShowCount + 1

UPDATE posts SET show_count = $newShowCount WHERE id = $pid AND show_count = $oldShowCount
```

At this point, if no race conditions occurred the row will update (rows update = 1).  If a race condition occurred, the update will fail (rows updated = 0).

Then check the # rows updated to verify it worked and repeat until it does.

Comment: $oldShowCount is what show_count currently is.  $incShowCount is $oldShowCount + 1.  This guarantees that you update it a maximum of once.

Comment: The only way that will happen in this scenario is that you are running the entire thing twice.  Time to start debugging to figure out why!

Comment: but why in localhost is fine?

Comment: Don't know.  There's definitely not enough information and likely can't be.  So, now's the time to hone your debugging skills!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common case.
You are running your script twice. Probably because browser is calling it twice. Check your rewrite rules.

Comment: in localhost this query fine.but in the internet host i have this problem.